# Why does unordered_map's emplace with piecewise_construct argument needs default constructor?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, default-constructor, emplace

I have an `unordered_map` which stores `<string, A>` pairs. I wanted to emplace pairs with this snippet:

```
        map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(name),
            std::forward_as_tuple(constructorArg1, constructorArg1, constructorArg1));
```

But if my `A` class doesn't have a default constructor then it fails to compile with this error:

> 'A::A': no appropriate default constructor available
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\VC\include\tuple 1180

Why does it need a default constructor and how can I avoid the use of it?

Comment: I think it happens, because VS 2015 instantiates all the methods along with the class instantiation. No default constructor should be required unless you touched a method (e.g. `operator[]`), that requires default construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` needs default constructor is because of `operator[]`. `map[key]` will construct new element using default constructor if `key` is not exist in `map`.

You can totally use map without default constructor. E.g. following program will compile with no error.

```
struct A {
    int x;
    A(int x) : x(x) {}
}; 

...

std::unordered_map<int, A> b;

b.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(1),
    std::forward_as_tuple(2));
b.at(1).x = 2;
```